# Show all labels with fviz_clust

Tags: r, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering, ggrepel

i have a question concerning hirarchical clustering with factoextra `fviz_clust()`, so actually ggplot2 i guess.

In my Factor map the labels look like this

[image]

but i want to have it, that way more labels are shown, especially in cluster one. I know there is a way to incooperate `ggrepel`, but i was not able to perfrom unfortunately. In this way, the labels "point" with a bar to the datapoint. That would be the best outcome.

the code looks like this:

```
factormap <- fviz_cluster(res.hcpc.Contr,
             geom = c("text","point"),
             repel = TRUE,            # Avoid label overlapping
             show.clust.cent = TRUE, # Show cluster centers
             palette = "lancet",         # Color palette see ?ggpubr::ggpar
             ggtheme = theme_bw()+
             
              theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size=15),
        axis.title.x =element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size=15),
        axis.title.y =element_text(size=20),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=25)))
```

i am sorry that i can not give a reproducible sample.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the solution was that i had to set the `max.overlaps` option of `ggrepel` to `inf` globally for the whole session.

```
options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)
```

Graph now

[image]